# Select row which has apostrophe value postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping

I want to select rows which has apostrophe value postgresql:

```
select * from table where column like '%'||chr(39)||'%'
```

But it doesn't work.

Table `buku`:

```
id             new_issn
-------------  --------
1.003.111.641  ''
1.003.111.642  ''
1.003.111.643  125698
```

```
select * from buku where new_issn like '%'||chr(39)||'%'
```

Answer (score 14):

An apostrophe can be escaped with another apostrophe. Try this:

```
select * from table where column like '%''%'
```

Reference: [Postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS).

Comment: @mu is too short : i have copy the value and paste it to my query

Comment: @nike: So you've got a pair of single quotes surrounded by double quotes. The query I've posted should work. Please post your actual query and some test rows in the question so we can debug further.

Comment: "10.0311.1641";"''" select * from buku where new_issn like '%''%'

Comment: @Nike: I'm sorry but I don't understand the beginning part of your comment.

Comment: I use this and works nicely.. SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE $$%'%$$